# Why is Jesus appointed heir? Heb 1:2

Tags: jesus, hebrews

We read the magnificent introduction to Hebrews.

> In many parts, and many ways, God of old having spoken to the fathers in the prophets, 2in these last days did speak to us in a Son, whom He appointed heir of all things, through whom also He did make the ages. Youngs

Why is Jesus "appointed heir of all things", if as it's widely believed, he made everything?

Comment: This question is not actually about the text being quoted. The question is about what is asserted to be 'widely believed'. What is 'curious' is  not the inheritance. What is purported to be 'curious' is that what is asserted to be 'widely believed' is, one has to assume, being suggested as a 'curiosity' in the context of inheritance.

Comment: @steveowen - Are you asking : **Was the Greek term " κληρονόμον " (klēronomos) appropriate to define a person who had already "possessed" the world (having made all things in it)**?

Comment: no, if he already possessed, why/how can he be heir? He doesn't make himself heir, God appoints him.

Comment: This might not be what your asking, just clarifying : **If a father supplies the architectural knowledge and materials for his son to make the father a house, was the house actually the son's (never the father's) because the son made it?**

Comment: The son didn't make it, so it's a moot point. God created.

Comment: Then a correct answer to your question would have to establish the "yhios" [Son] of Hebrews 1:2 was also among the Elohim of Genesis 1?

Answer (score 2):

The text which explains what it means for Christ to be "appointed heir of all things" is Romans 4:13. As someone has commented, the question should not be about the Son of God (as the Word of God) having made everything that was made (John 1:3). That is a distinct question in its own right (which question, with many answers, has already been given on Stack Biblical Hermeneutics).

But there is a biblical explanation for what it means for Christ to be "appointed heir of all things" and a good starting point is God's promise to Abraham regarding heirs. I quote this explanation from the book below, which starts by showing how Jesus Christ is everything in the Book of the Revelation of Jesus Christ, the last book of the Bible:

> "It is a question of divine rights over the creature, and over
> Creation... The book may concern his things because they are *his*
> things. For example, no matter that the promised land might have
> prefigured the realm of his dominion, in fact this figure never was
> intended to represent less than *all* that had been lost in the Fall.
> The whole Creation was in view. To suppose the kingdom to have been
> but a small tract of land in the Middle East altogether misses the
> point.
>
> The Jews may have said of the heir to what they thought of as the
> promised land, "This is the heir; come, let us kill him, and the
> inheritance shall be ours [Mat.21:38]. But like the whole of blinded
> and darkened religion, Jewish or Christian; liberal or modern
> evangelical, they neither knew the greatness of the heir, the extent
> of the inheritance, nor the purpose of God for the heir to the throne.
>
> Paul - enlightened from heaven - understood these things, He knew that
> when Abraham had been promised the land, the ultimate meaning of this
> introductory figure of promise was that the Seed of Abraham - which is
> Christ, Mt. 1:1 - should sit upon the throne of world dominion and
> inherit the whole earth: 'For the promise, that he should be ***heir
> of the world***, was not to Abraham, *or to his Seed*, through the
> law, but through the righteousness of faith', Romans 4:13
>
> Heir of the *world?* But however should *this* come to pass? ...In the
> counsels of God from the foundation of the world redemption was not in
> question. The question was, How should Christ - *with* his redeemed
> people - become heir of the world, actually occupying the throne of
> world dominion. *That* was the sealed book" [in Rev.5:1, which only
> the glorified Christ could unseal]. *The Revelation of Jesus Christ*, pp 110-111, John Metcalfe

Chapter 4 of Revelation shows the Almighty on his throne of glory. Context shows he is indisputably asserting his rights over his creation (verse 11). Rev. 5:11-12 shows that Christ, this once-slain-Lamb, is worthy "to receive power and riches and wisdom and strength and honour and glory and blessing." He had all these things in heaven, but looked for them on earth. When he suddenly returns to claim his rights, he will be looking for faith - but will he even find that (Luke 18:8)?

This shows that the *real* starting point goes right back to creation, for God is sovereign over all his creation, and at no point has he ever relinquished his right to rule (including ruling over the earth). As the book points out:

> "Nothing is given up that Almighty God created: nor is the truth that
> **he created it for Christ** ever relinquished. Man has stolen it, but every single right to each one particle of Creation is claimed in
> heaven... The earth is the Lord's and the fulness thereof (Ps.24:1);
> crown rights are claimed; the Maker's rights, absolute rights, the
> ownership rights of Almighty God, pertain to all Creation and absolute
> creature worship." (*Ibid.* pp 112-113)

The Son ***has been*** appointed heir of all things, which was decided upon before ever any creation started. And the Almighty created in total conjunction with the eternal Son and the everlasting Spirit, that everything created is created **for Christ.** When Christ appears in glory to start the Day of Resurrection and Judgment, every knee will bend, in heaven and on earth, to him - the heir now having claimed his rights. The Father will have set the Son as king on his holy hill, and the Son will have asked for his inheritance - "the uttermost parts of the earth" for his possession (Psalm 2). To this end he was appointed from before the foundation of the world.

Comment: I'm confused by, "the question should not be about the Son of God" But Heb IS about the Son.

Comment: @steveowen   I said the Q should not be about the Son of God as the Word of God having made everything that was made (John 1:3). The Q should be about why Jesus has been appointed heir of all things and I answered accordingly.

Comment: @steveowen  I simply do not understand your comment, above. I am totally including the Son in the entirety of my answer. My answer is all about why the Son has been appointed heir of all things.

Comment: Pls just explain my first request properly. You said, "the question should not be about the Son of God" Why not?

Comment: @steveowen  Ask that question yourself, as a separate, new question. Comments are not for such extended exchanges.

Comment: Very clear and concise. This shows the resolution of all things by Christ's resurrection and ascendancy unto his glorious return and Kingship.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't have to be interpreted literally since the context showed that Jesus pre-existed creation and is the agent of creation (i.e. God created all things through him). Jesus being appointed to inherit all things means all things *belongs* to him in Hebrews 1:2 in the same sense Yahweh is said to inherit all the earth in Psalm 82:8.

Yahweh himself *inherits* all the earth (Psalm 82:8). The NIV translated it to mean that all the earth *belongs* to Yahweh.

> "Arise, **O God**, judge the earth; for **you shall inherit all the nations**! Psalm 82:8 (ESV)

Answer (score 1):

Hebrews 1:

> 1 In many parts, and many ways, God of old having spoken to the fathers in the prophets, 2in these last days did speak to us in a Son, whom He appointed **heir** of all things, through whom also He did **make** the ages. Youngs

The Son made all things. Then he was appointed to inherit all things.

Why is Jesus "appointed heir of all things", if as it's widely believed, he made everything?

It is useful at times to distinguish between the eternal personhood of the Son from his temporal roles/functions.

The Son as an eternal person made all things. Unfortunately, sin spoiled the world and John 1:

> 10
> He was in the world, and though the world was made through him, the world did not recognize him.

One of his roles was to die to redeem the world. After that, he earned another one of his roles, Matthew 28:

> 18
> Then Jesus came to them and said, “All authority in heaven and on earth **has been given** to me.

Comment: you seem to be confusing logos with son. "The Son as an eternal person made all things" is without support.

Comment: There is one support from e.g. https://www.gotquestions.org/eternal-Sonship.html

Comment: It is also confused, "it was “the Son” who created all things (Colossians 1:13-16; Hebrews 1:2)," same old 'proof-texts' without merit. You know I mean 'biblical support'.

Comment: Did you read it? It cited several biblical passages. If you need more supports just Google "The Son as an eternal person made all things".